# Why not allocate the UIWindow object in the UIViewController subclass?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

Suppose the application will only use a single-purpose view controller.  Is there anything inherently bad with allocating the required UIWindow object as a member of the view controller subclass?

The programming guide does not provide any examples built this way, although they also don't seem to emphasize whether that's truly allowed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was asking the same question and found yours. After a look around, I found that going back to basics was the correct thing to do, so

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: by all means, stick with the docs.  it's just that I was needing to roll all windowing calls to a single management class.

Comment: What I did is used the AppDelegate to mange the window as it is always accessible by [UIApplication sharedApllication].delegate.